# Do I have a data leak?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, data-preprocessing

I'm working on trying to predict close prices for EUR/USD one day ahead and I've created a base model to start using pipelines. However, the results are too good to be true and I'm certain I've got a data leak somewhere however I can't find it.

Here is the code for running the model and creating the pipeline:

```
estimators = []
estimators.append(("strings_to_floats", StringToFloat(string_features)))
estimators.append(("series_supervised", SeriesToSupervised(n_in)))
estimators.append(("current_feature_remove",RemoveCurrentFeatures(features=current_features_remove)))

# Model pipeline
estimators.append(("SGD", SGDRegressor(max_iter=50000, tol=1e-3)))
model = Pipeline(estimators)
```

```
# Evaluate Pipeline
model.fit(train_X_, train_y_)
predictions = model.predict(test_X_)
```

The `SeriesToSupervised` code is here:

```
def series_to_supervised(self, data, n_in=5, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
        """
        Frame a time series as a supervised learning dataset.
        Arguments:
            data: Sequence of observations as a list or NumPy array.
            n_in: Number of lag observations as input (X).
            n_out: Number of observations as output (y).
            dropnan: Boolean whether or not to drop rows with NaN values.
        Returns:
            Pandas DataFrame of series framed for supervised learning.
        """
        old_names = data.columns
        n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=old_names)
        cols, names = list(), list()
        # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
        for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
            cols.append(df.shift(i))
            names += [('%s(t-%d)' % (old_names[j], i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
        for i in range(0, n_out):
            cols.append(df.shift(-i))
            if i == 0:
                names += [('%s' % (old_names[j])) for j in range(n_vars)]
            else:
                names += [('%s' % (old_names[j])) for j in range(n_vars)]
        # Remove spaces in names
        for i in range(len(names)):
            names[i-1] = names[i-1].strip()
        # put it all together
        agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
        agg.columns = names
        # drop rows with NaN values
        if dropnan:
            agg.dropna(inplace=True)
        return agg
```

The `RemoveCurrentFeatures` simply goes over this list: ["Open","High","Low","Change %","Price"] and removes these columns.

The dataset starts of with the columns in the list above plus a "Date". After the data prep, the data frame has the columns in the form of "Price(t-n_in)" where n_in is the number of days to lag the data.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while now and I'm sure something is wrong here.

EDIT:
Here is how I do my test and train split:

```
# Invert dataframe
    data = data.iloc[::-1]

    # Split each set into train and test sets
    names = data.columns.values

    dataFrame_train = pd.DataFrame(data[:int(data.shape[0]*train_test_split)], columns=names)
    train_X = dataFrame_train#.iloc[:, 0:-1]
    train_y = dataFrame_train["Price"]
    train_y = train_y.tail(train_y.shape[0] - n_in)

    dataFrame_test = pd.DataFrame(data[int(data.shape[0]*train_test_split):], columns=names)
    test_X = dataFrame_test#.iloc[:, 0:-1]
    test_y = dataFrame_test["Price"]
    test_y = test_y.tail(test_y.shape[0] - n_in)

    dataFrame_test = dataFrame_test.tail(dataFrame_test.shape[0] - n_in)
```

Comment: The results I get with this is roughly a 0.92 R2 score and with a simple one-day trading strategy it makes 20% per year.

Comment: How do you train/test split?

Comment: I updated that in the question for you. The split is 0.7.

Comment: What is `Invert dataframe` for? Do you train on beginning of the timeline or the ending, after all?

Comment: It's just because the raw data starts from the last date and goes to the current date. So I inverted it because that's what my code was set up to handle.